# Schreiben + An + Surname

Tags: standard-german

What will be correct:

> Soll ich an Dr Mueller schreiben um meinen Brief zu errinern?

or

> Soll ich Dr Mueller schreiben um meinen Brief zu errinern?

I have found in a dictinary "ich schreibe dich einen Brief". Does it mean the first version is correct?

Comment: *Ich schreibe dich einen Brief* is wrong. It ought to be *... **dir** einen Brief*.

Comment: I think "*errinern*" should be "*erinnern*"

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer

> Soll ich Dr. Mueller schreiben, um an meinen Brief zu erinnern?

It is also possible to use

> Soll ich an Dr. Mueller schreiben, um an meinen Brief zu erinnern?

You can use *jemandem schreiben* (Dativ) or *an jemanden schreiben* (*an* + Akkusativ).

It must be "…, um *an* meinen Brief zu erinnern".

Especially in this example sentence the first variant is stylistically better because it avoids repeating the word "an". (suggested in [phipsgabler](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1626/phipsgabler)'s comment)

---

Note: The correct spelling of the name might be "Mueller" or "Müller". I adhere to the spelling from the question because it may be the correct spelling of the person's name, which is not known here. The spelling "Müller" is more common, but it can be written as "Mueller" if the letter "ü" is not available.

Comment: I'd say the first is stilistically better because it avoids repeating the _an_. But semantically, they are indeed equivalent.